# Filtro com form externo com jquery datatables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-datatables

Estou tentando fazer um filtro externo a partir de um form externo

Até então, para uma simples busca genérica,o `jquery datatables` utiliza o parametro `'sSearch'`

Para isso, eu apenas faço

```
  var grid = new $.fn.dataTable.Api('.e-grid');
  grid.search('Teste');
  grid.draw();
```

Tudo certo, porém eu preciso fazer um filtro um pouco mais complexo, a qual os dados do form de filtro não estão na coluna.
Falo isso, pois todo filtro um pouco mais complexo que achei de exemplo, era apenas das colunas que já existiam no datatable

A pergunta é, como eu faço para passar outros parametros para esse filtro? além do default que é `sSearch`

OBS: O filtro é via `Ajax`, e como Server Side estou usando `Asp.net MVC`

Answer (score 1):

Segue um exemplo abaixo:

```
var oTable = $("#dataTableCustom").dataTable({
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": globalSource,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.getJSON(sSource, aoData, function (json) {
                var parsedJSON = $.parseJSON(json);
                fnCallback(parsedJSON)
            });
        },
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({
                "name": "listName",
                "value": wcfListName
            })
            aoData.push({
                "name": "columnNames",
                "value": wcfColumnsToDisplay
            })
            aoData.push({
                "name": "SortingDirection",
                "value": wcfSortDirection
            })
            aoData.push({
                "name": "sortingColumns",
                "value": wcfSortColumns
            })

        }
    });
```

O Valor do "value" pode ser um imput também, ex:

```
"value": $(".meuiinput").val();
```

O exemplo acima foi retirado desse [LINK](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10413/passing-custom-parameters-from-jquery-data-table-fnserverdata-to-my-custom-web-service#), do forúm do `Jquery DataTables`